# DataGridView - Adding columns without constant horizontal scroll bar update (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I need to add several (say 20) columns to it dynamicly. When I do it like this

```
foreach (var columnName in ColumnNames)
     dataGridView.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName);
```

horizontal scroll bar tries to stay up to date every time new column is added. So user sees strange scroll bar shrinking. I need to update horizontal scroll bar only once when all columns are added. How do I accomplish this?
P.S.  I tried to do it like this:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView)).BeginInit();
dataGridView.SuspendLayout();

foreach (var columnName in ColumnNames)
{
     dataGridView.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName);
}

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView)).EndInit();
dataGridView.ResumeLayout(false);
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DataGridViewColumnCollection.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange.aspx).  This might help with the updating.

```
dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(Columns);
```

An example of AddRange given columns name (untested but should work):

```
// Assuming ColumnNames is a list of column names    
DataGridViewColumn[] columns_to_add = 
   new DataGridViewColumn[ColumnNames.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Count; i++)
{
   // Add whatever column type you want
   columns_to_add[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   columns_to_add[i].HeaderText = ColumnNames[i];
   columns_to_add[i].Name = ColumnNames[i];
}
dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(columns_to_add);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to construct `DataGridViewColumn` knowing only it's name?

Comment: @StuffHappens - I added a quick example